# Can not connect to server (from android emulator to java server)

Tags: java, android, server

I have written a server in java and a client in android, but I am not able to find the server using my android code.

Note 1: I used the exact same code in java and I could easily connect to server.

Note 2: I used "10.0.2.2" and also "my computer ip" as mentioned in some threads in Stackoverflow, but none of them worked.

Note 3: I am using android studio

I would appreciate if anybody can help me with that.

his I put inside onCreate:

```
cl1 = new Client("192.168.189.1");

cl1.startRunning();
```

And this is my client class:

```
package com.example.tavoes;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.util.Log;

public class Client {


private ObjectOutputStream output;
private String message = "";
private String serverIp;
private Socket connection;
private Scanner scanner;

// constructor
public Client(String host) {
super();
serverIp = host;
}

// connect to server
public void startRunning() {

try {
   connectToServer();            
    setupStream();
   whileChatting();
} catch (EOFException eofException) {
    eofException.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    ioException.printStackTrace();
} /*finally {
    closeChat();
}*/
}

// connect to server
private void connectToServer() {

try {
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIp), 4444);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// setup streams to send and receive messages
private void setupStream() throws IOException {
output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
output.flush();
//input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
//System.out.println("Inside Streams are setup!");
}

// While chatting with server
private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
//do {
//output.flush();

output.writeObject("<Request connection  \"1\" />");

scanner=new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
message = scanner.nextLine();
//System.out.println(message);
//message = (String) input.readObject();
}

// close the streams and sockets
private void closeChat() {
try {
    output.close();
    //input.close();
    connection.close();
    //System.out.println("Closing connection");
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    ioException.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: do you allow network connection from the app? did you try it on a real device?

Comment: I placed the code in the first andswer

Comment: @Skaros Ilias: I am using the server in local device, so I think network permission wouldnt be needed. And also I need to present it in emulator, so real device wouldnt help.

Comment: it is not local device. local device is the android device, not your pc. your pc is a device outside of the android "world". i believe that you do need network permissions. it wouldn't hurt to try

Comment: @SkarosIlias I did that, but now I get "NetworkOnMainThreadException".

Comment: just saw your edit. is 192.168.189.1 the ip of the computer where the emulator is running? about the exception, you can not have network connection on the main thread. you need a secondary thread, or even better use AsyncTask

Comment: Thanks for the respond. yes it is. I also used "10.0.2.2", but still I got the same problem

Comment: wait a min. did you got the exception AFTER you enabled the network connection? that means that there was NO NETWORK connection before. that must be your solution. Enable network access and use AsyncTask

Comment: @SkarosIlias yes you are right. I made 2 mistakes: Not including network permissions in manifest, and Calling the network socket in the same thread as my activity. Now its fixed, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to tag it as solved for future reference:
in order to create any connection using the network you need

1. Allow the application to use the network by including the permision
   to the manifest
2. Do all the networking activity on a seperate thread
   than the main thread, or use AsyncTask